# How to put parent and child field from single entity in typeorm

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

what can be the entity to put parent and child from the same entity .. and get as parent  and child  relation resultset

```js
@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

}
```

I want the output as

```js
{
    id: 1
    photos: [{
         name: "Timber",
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use `toDto()` like the below example

```js
@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    // Create a toDto
    toDto(arg=''){
        return {
            id: this.id,
            photos: [this.name],
            meta: arg
        }
    }
}
```

In the service, when you want to return the entity, return founded `user` with `toDto`

```js
let result = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { id: 1}})
return result.toDto()
```

Also you can pass arguments